# D3 Path with random colored lines

Tags: d3.js, colors, path, line

Following code generates a random color d3 path using line-generator function and dataArray created in for loop. How can I make *EACH* line in the path have a different random color?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
     x = Math.random()*$(window).width();
     y = Math.random()*$(window).height();
     rc = d3.rgb( Math.random()*255, Math.random()*255, Math.random()*255 );
     dataArray[i] = { x:x, y:y, color:rc };
}

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("height","100%").attr("width","100%");

var line = d3.line()
         .x(function(d,i){return d.x})
         .y(function(d,i){return d.y});

var path = svg.selectAll("path").data(dataArray).enter().append('path')
           .attr('d', function(d){return line(dataArray)})
           .attr('stroke-width', 5)
           .attr('stroke', function(d) { return d.color});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create your lines with only 2 points, not all of them (ie create several paths, not one)

```
line([dataArray[i], dataArray[i]]
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Btim/a0L961vs/)

Comment: As you mentioned, I could go with several paths, however, I am trying to figure out if it is possible to have a single multi-color path to animate it once. For example, I had the following code to draw my path which becomes inactive if I use several path with length zero.  
    

`var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path
     .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
      .transition()
        .duration(10000)
        //.ease("bounceOut")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);`

Comment: @user2367663 you cannot have one line with several colors in svg